# How to randomly create null values in pandas dataframe and store original values in the replaced cells?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Lets say I have a dataframe df:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 3 |

and I want to create random null values say 25% per column something like this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null |
| null | 4 | 5 |
| 5 | null | 2 |
| null | 3 | null |

Now i want to save original values of these null values may be as an array or dict?

so that I have original values of only  replaced nulls.

```py
Original ={'A2': 3,'A4': 2, 'B1':2, 'B3':6}

Replaced ={'A2': null,'A4': null, 'B1':null, 'B3':null}
```

Ideally I want to have original values for the replaced cells in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Starting data: `df`

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  6
1  3  4  5
2  5  6  2
3  2  3  3
```

Get a random sample of indices/columns:
`df_nulls = df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.25))`

```
     A    B    C
0  NaN  2.0  NaN
2  5.0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

**Note:** `NaN` represent unselected values

Using `numpy` you can get the coordinates for non-null values:
`rows, cols = np.where(df_nulls.notnull())`

```
print(rows)
# [0 1 2]
```

```
print(cols)
# [1 0 2]
```

Build your `Original` `dict`:
`Original = {f"{df.columns[c]}{r}": df.iloc[r, c] for r, c in zip(rows, cols)}`

```
print(Original)
# {'B0': 2, 'A1': 3, 'C2': 2}
```

Build your `Replaced` `dict`:
`Replaced = {k: float("nan") for k in Original}`

```
print(Replaced)
# {'B0': nan, 'A1': nan, 'C2': nan}
```

Complete the replacement:

```
for r, c in zip(rows, cols):
    df.iloc[r, c] = float("nan")

print(df)
```

```
     A    B    C
0  1.0  NaN  6.0
1  NaN  4.0  5.0
2  5.0  6.0  NaN
3  2.0  3.0  3.0
```